# Is checking one randomly chosen digital signature is enough for verifying multiple signed file?

Tags: java, certificate, x509certificate, digital-signature, bouncycastle

Imagine, I have multiple detached signatures of some binary file and they stored in different .sig files. **When somebody modifies file, all signatures will become invalid**.

For xml an enveloped signature is widely used. Cheking it is more difficult - one have to extract last `ds:Signature` element, check signature, remove the last element and check current last `ds:Signature` element and so on. But XML modification anyway will break the last signature, why I have to check others?

The only explanation - each `ds:Signature` or PKCS7-signature contains public key certificate with information about signer, key validity period, information for revoke-checking. **Usually, verification process is not only checking hashes, but providing information about signer and this is the only reason for iterate over all signarures, am I right?**

So, when I want to verify multiple signed file and provide info about signers can I make small optimization - exract info for all signatures but perform hash checking only in one randomly chosen signature?

One more question - how store multiple PKCS7 signatures in one file? I'm using **bouncycastle** Java library. Does it have some method to concatenate signatures and extract them from one file? I don't want to manually store all signatures in one .sig file, care about signature delimiter, is is available in bouncy castle out of the box?

**UPDATE**

My BouncyCastle signing code

```
    Certificate[] certchain = (Certificate[]) keystore.getCertificateChain(alias);

    final List<Certificate> certlist = new ArrayList<Certificate>();

    for (int i = 0, length = certchain == null ? 0 : certchain.length; i < length; i++) {
        certlist.add(certchain[i]);
    }

    Store certstore = new JcaCertStore(certlist);

    Certificate cert = keystore.getCertificate(alias);

    ContentSigner signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA1withRSA").setProvider("BC").
            build((PrivateKey) (keystore.getKey(alias, getPassword().toCharArray())));

    CMSSignedDataGenerator generator = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();

    generator.addSignerInfoGenerator(new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider("BC").
            build()).build(signer, (X509Certificate) cert));

    generator.addCertificates(certstore);
    CMSTypedData cmsdata = new CMSProcessableByteArray(content);
    CMSSignedData signeddata = generator.generate(cmsdata, false);
```

As you see generate method's second argument is false, which means, that I'm generating non-enveloped signature==.sig file does not contain data.

Verifying code

```
CMSSignedData cms = new CMSSignedData(new CMSProcessableByteArray(contents.getBytes()), signature);
            Store store = cms.getCertificates();
            SignerInformationStore signers = cms.getSignerInfos();
            Collection c = signers.getSigners();
            Iterator it = c.iterator();

            while (it.hasNext()) {
                SignerInformation signer = (SignerInformation) it.next();
                Collection certCollection = store.getMatches(signer.getSID());
                Iterator certIt = certCollection.iterator();
                X509CertificateHolder certHolder = (X509CertificateHolder) certIt.next();
                cert = new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider("BC").getCertificate(certHolder);
                ok = signer.verify(new JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder().setProvider("BC").build(cert));
                if (!ok) break; // probably should remove it
            }
```

**Question - may I do something like this (description below) in BouncyCastle out of the box?**

Make detached signatures enveloped - first sign = hash(doc)-->appendToSigFile, second sign = hash(doc+sigFile)-->appendToSigFile and so on. Is such approach OK to imitate XML's enveloped signature?

Comment: Can you be sure all those separate signature files sign the identical document? Is it not possible that one signature file has been created after the manipulation?

Comment: Furthermore, a single pkcs7 signature container can contain any number of parallel and counter signatures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually ask a number of questions. Thus,

1. *when I want to verify multiple signed file and provide info about signers can I make small optimization - extract info for all signatures but perform hash checking only in one randomly chosen signature?*

If you are sure (e.g. by organisational reasons) that all those signatures initially correctly signed the same document, you may consider this optimization. But even then you should not randomly choose a signature and instead prefer those with the more confidable algorithms.

And if you do optimize like that, you definitively should not claim that *all* signatures are still valid but that *a chosen one* is. If you don't test something, you should not claim you did.

2. *But XML modification anyway will break the last signature, why I have to check others?*

It very much depends on your use case. If (as above) you are sure (e.g. by organisational reasons) that all those signatures initially correctly signed their respective document revision, checking the outermost signature may suffice.

If on the other hand the document was forwarded from one person the the other to sign and manipulations you check for may have occurred at any step, you have to check every one of these signatures to be sure that everyone signed the content without unwanted changes.

And if not each XML signature did sign at least the same data as the respectively contained one using at least as strict a canonicalization as that one (XML signatures can be very selective on which elements they sign and what deviations they allow), you definitively have to check each one.

3. *Usually, verification process is not only checking hashes, but providing information about signer and this is the only reason for iterate over all signatures, am I right?*

Obviously... If you only wanted to check hashes, you only would store hashes (ok, unless there are political or marketing related reasons that is...). Signing is about making provable that specific people saw and accepted some specific data for a specific purpose under specific circumstances. Your question only seems to want to consider the *specific data* part.

4. *how store multiple PKCS7 signatures in one file?*

PKCS#7 signature containers can contain any number of parallel signatures of the same data and additional counter signatures.

If you look at the specification [RFC 2315](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2315) you will find:

> The signed-data content type shall have ASN.1 type SignedData:

> ```
> SignedData ::= SEQUENCE {
> ```

```
     version Version,
     digestAlgorithms DigestAlgorithmIdentifiers,
     contentInfo ContentInfo,
     certificates [0] IMPLICIT ExtendedCertificatesAndCertificates OPTIONAL,
     crls [1] IMPLICIT CertificateRevocationLists OPTIONAL,
     signerInfos SignerInfos }
```

> ```
> DigestAlgorithmIdentifiers ::= SET OF DigestAlgorithmIdentifier
> ```

> ```
> SignerInfos ::= SET OF SignerInfo
> ```

> ...

> signerInfos is a collection of per-signer
> information. There may be any number of elements in the
> collection, including zero.

BouncyCastle provides many utility functionality, also for this, but as you didn't show how you use BC, it's hard to explain how you should change your BC use.

5. *Make detached signatures enveloped - first sign = hash(doc)-->appendToSigFile, second sign = hash(doc+sigFile)-->appendToSigFile and so on. Is such approach OK to imitate XML's enveloped signature?*

You can use countersignatures which would work equivalently to your design.

Alternatively... PKCS#7 signature containers allow you to embed the signed content, it does not need to be detached. Thus, you can embed the original content in the first signature container, then embed this signature container in the second one etc. This would make implicitly clear what each signature signs.

Comment: You use **generator.addSignerInfoGenerator** once in your code. If BC is well-designed in this respect, you should be able to call it more often for the same **CMSSignedDataGenerator**. CAsES might show a solution for your appended question.

Comment: What is CAsES? Abbreviation for some class? And I'm also interested in logical correctness of detached-enveloped imitation described  in update - is it OK?

Comment: CAdES can be considered an extension of CMS which in turn can be considered an extension of PKCS#7. You can use the CMS counter signature mechanism which resembles your *detached-enveloped imitation* in a standardized way.

Answer (score 0):

Digital signatures aren't there just to provide integrity checking. They are also a means of proving, legally if necessary, that that person signed that file. It's like a signature on a cheque. You must therefore verify them all. If one fails, you have a forgery on your hands. If they all fail, you have a corrupt document or a joint forgery. In either case it's useless and should be rejected.